# Ruin theory problem

Tags: probability

An insurance company has a portfolio of two year policies. Aggregate annual claims from the portfolio follow an exponential distribution with mean $10$ ( independent from year to year ). Annual premiums of $15$ are payable at the start of each year. The insurer starts with no capital. We need to calculate the probability that the insurer is not ruined by the end of the second year.

I tried solving this in the following manner :

Let , U = Initial capital , U(t) = Capital at time t , c = Premium per unit time , S(1) = Aggregate annual claim. { U(t) = U + ct - s(t) }

We need to find $Probability( U(2) > 0 )$.

=> $P( 30 - S(2) > 0)$

=> $P( S(2) < 30 )$

Now , we're given $S(1)$~ $Exp(0.1)$ , thus $S(2)$~ $Gamma ( 2 , 0.1)$.

And we know that , when $ X$ ~ $Exp( \lambda )$ then , $2X$~$Gamma ( \alpha  , \lambda )$.

Thus using this result and then using the $Chi-Square$ result I was able to calculate the probability as $0.8009$

But the solution is given as follows :

Let $X$ and $Y$ be the aggregate amount of claims in the first and the second year respectively , thus the probability is found out as :

$P( X < 15\:\: \&\:\: X+Y < 30 )$ or $P( X < 15\:\: \&\:\: Y < 30-X )$ which gives the value $0.702$.

I know the values come out to be different but isn't the first solution good 'approximation'  to the second one ? 
Since the second method becomes a little clumsy , isn't the first method considerable ?

Please help !

Comment: What is the actual question here? Do you understand why your solution does not give the correct (exact) answer? Also, is there a typo in your description of the second method (the terms in the sum are equal and I don't see why they should be summed)?

Comment: Your first solution seems to be $P(X+Y \lt 30)$.  This is not the same as $P(X \lt 15\,\& \, X+Y \lt 30)$ as it also includes $P(X \ge 15\,\& \,X+Y \lt 30)$, which as you have noted has a probability of almost $0.1$ and represents the probability of profits from the second year being sufficient to pay off the losses from the first year. Unfortunately by that stage the insurance company has already bean ruined

Comment: Made an edit , it's "or" in the place of "+" , thanks for pointing it out.. @JuhoKokkala

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: The insurance company starts with no capital? What insurance regulator would allow that?  The insurance company should reinsure to offload some of the risk.